# Как сделать выборку по числу из базы, которое находится в строке

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Например, в базе имеются строки с текстом `field=100`, `field=10`, `field = 1000`, `field = 50`.

Как мне сделать выборку из кода тех сущностей, в которых `field` не больше *60*?

Пока решаю проблему с помощью `string.IndexOf()` и забираю строки где число имеет две цифры, но это костыль.

UPD.
С примерами в комментариях выскакивает ошибка:
Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Мне нужно сделать выборку из базы, а не из IEnumerable в памяти.

Comment: что значит число имеет 2 цифры? 99 это две цифры?

Comment: Ты не рассматриваешь чтобы хранить числа в БД не как строку?

Comment: @Bald56rus, да.

Comment: @progpow, рассматриваю, но очевидно в данной ситуации это невозможно

Answer (score 5):

```
public class TestTable
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

var data = context.TestTable.Where(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Value.Split(new char[] {'='}))<60);
```

ну я бы попробовал как то так, исходя из того что Вы написали.

а вариант изменения структуры не расматривается вовсе? например поля параметр и значение?

Comment: К сожалению очень сложно рефакторить базу которая в продакшене, при динамическом изменении требований)

Comment: @anweledig тогда то что Вам написал Qwertiy более универсально ввиду регулярного выражения.

Comment: @Bald56rus Мне думается парсинг ёмкая операция, не уверен что это нужно, если  не требуется значение.

Answer (score 5):

http://ideone.com/ZXOze6

```
data.Where(s => { var m=Regex.Match(s, @"\d+"); return m.Success && int.Parse(m.Value)<60; })
```

Comment: Как отработает подобный запрос при наличии текста в строке?

Comment: @progpow, а что не так с текстом? Он просто выберет первое число.

Comment: да, сорь, не заметил сразу

Answer (score 1):

Можешь воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^|[^\d])[0-5]?[0-9]\s*$");
regex.IsMatch(testedString);
```